# GoogleSpreadsheet is not a constructor error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

```js
(node:13696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: GoogleSpreadsheet is not a constructor
```

Currently getting this error when trying to define GoogleSpreadsheet. Not sure what the issue could be here.

```js
async function accessSpreadsheet() {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('166SrAlBzhYXLxxIrHCQR333y_w3pcxeG7rV3bkjAp2U');
    await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
    const info = await promisify(dox.getInfo)();
    const sheet = info.worksheets[0];

    const input = {
        transcript: data,
        ticket: message.channel.name
    }

    await promisify(sheet.addRow);
}

accessSpreadsheet();
```

Above is my code, not all of it, but everything to do with google spreadsheet.

Comment: Please can you show your includes?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using version 3 you may need to import it like this:

const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');

Answer (score 3):

You either have to re-install your google-spreadsheet api to 2.0.6 just to make it work

```
npm install google-spreadsheet@2.0.6
```

or just follow the new version of implementation from the docs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet