# Error Connecting Google Sheets to Node JS

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to have a spreadsheet interact with node js and I'm having connectivity issues. I don't quite know where I'm going wrong and I can't seem to find a remedy to my situation. My code is below and it is a mix of Twilio and what I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61048269/googlespreadsheet-is-not-a-constructor-error):

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const creds = require('./credentials.json');

// spreadsheet key is the long id in the sheets URL

async function accessSpreadsheet() {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('XXX');
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
    client_email: creds.client_email,
    private_key: creds.private_key,
  });

  await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets
  console.log(doc.title);

  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; // or use doc.sheetsById[id]
  console.log(sheet.title);
  console.log(sheet.rowCount);

}

accessSpreadsheet();
```

I'm new to JavaScript so I don't really know how to properly handle these errors. My error messages are below:

```
(node:15432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: doc.loadInfo is not a function
    at accessSpreadsheet (/home/spreadsheet.js:13:13)
(node:15432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15432) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
/home/index.js:77
      cb()
      ^

TypeError: cb is not a function
    at /home/google-spreadsheet/index.js:77:7
    at /home/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/jwtclient.js:119:5
    at /home/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/jwtclient.js:138:16
    at Request._callback (/home/node_modules/gtoken/lib/index.js:228:14)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:291:20)
```

Comment: Can you provide the line 77 of index.js?

Comment: What version of "google-spreadsheet" are you using?

Comment: I'm unsure what version of "google-spreadsheet" I am using; How could I find out?

Comment: i am having the same issue did you find a solution ?